# Getting IDENTITY_PROVIDER_LOGIN_ERROR with keycloak, OAuth authentication with Github, "federatedIdentityModel" is null

Tags: kubernetes, helm, nginx, keycloak

I am running KeyCloak as one of the services in a K3s cluster to provide identity management for another service on the cluster, both of which is behind Ngnix. After deleting Github(the initial identity provider during initial set up) and try to add it back, I can't authenticate myself via github anymore. The error shows:
[dashboard_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWt1T.png)

This OAuth application creation on Github works before, so the configuration is correct.

The error I got from the namespace running KeyCloak after running `kubectl logs [pod-name] -n [namespace]`:

```bash
2023-12-30 11:41:56,801 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-311) type=REFRESH_TOKEN_ERROR, realmId=fsome-realm-id, clientId=security-admin-console, userId=null, ipAddress=internal_api_address, error=invalid_token, grant_type=refresh_token, client_auth_method=client-secret
2023-12-30 18:07:29,073 ERROR [org.keycloak.broker.oidc.AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider] (executor-thread-320) Failed to make identity provider oauth callback: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.keycloak.models.FederatedIdentityModel.getToken()" because "federatedIdentityModel" is null
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.IdentityBrokerService.updateToken(IdentityBrokerService.java:1046)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.IdentityBrokerService.updateFederatedIdentity(IdentityBrokerService.java:1000)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.IdentityBrokerService.authenticated(IdentityBrokerService.java:611)
    at org.keycloak.broker.oidc.AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider$Endpoint.authResponse(AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider.java:517)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor705.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:154)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:118)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:560)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:452)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:413)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:321)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:378)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:174)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:142)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:168)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:131)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:33)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:429)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:240)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:154)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:321)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:157)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:82)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:147)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.handle(VertxRequestHandler.java:84)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.handle(VertxRequestHandler.java:44)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1284)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:177)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:141)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.options.HttpServerCommonHandlers$1.handle(HttpServerCommonHandlers.java:58)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.options.HttpServerCommonHandlers$1.handle(HttpServerCommonHandlers.java:36)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1284)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:177)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:141)
    at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.integration.web.QuarkusRequestFilter.lambda$createBlockingHandler$0(QuarkusRequestFilter.java:82)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:576)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

2023-12-30 18:07:29,074 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-320) type=IDENTITY_PROVIDER_LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=some_realm_id, clientId=dashboard, userId=null, ipAddress=some_api_address, error=identity_provider_login_failure, identity_provider=github, redirect_uri=https://actual_server_url/, identity_provider_identity=my_github_username, code_id=3c1460c4-10ad-4f4a-80db-2e93609e70db
```

Does anyone know what to do if federatedIdentityModel is null?

### Expected behavior be like:

1. The federatedIdentityModel shouldn't be null
2. I should be able to authenticate myself via Github